# Is it possible for a Java application to connect to a host from multiple IP addresses?

Tags: java, sockets

Is there a way to open multiple socket connections from a single Java application (Hosted within tomcat) and have each of the sockets appear to originate from a different IP address?

**Background:**

My team are in the process of planning how we are going to integrate with a third party system, we've been contracted to write an adaptor for this system, and we don't have very much detail on apart from an API doc.

The doc specifies a TCP/IP based protocol, which allows a client to login to it.

The documentation specifies that only one connection will be allowed from a given IP address/user. Although it's ambiguous whether it will allow multiple connections from a single IP address with different user names.

We need to have a pool of connections open as our integration piece will be acting as a proxy and will need to have multiple connections open in parallel, we are hoping that having unique user names will be enough, but as we've not even been provided with a test system we want to have all out bases covered.

Comment: `appear to originate` so you mean IP spoofing?

Comment: To originate connections from different IP addresses you will need to define them on the actual box - you can't spoof IP addresses as there is no way for a response to get back and if TCP it will never complete the 3-way handshake. If you have multiple IP addresses defined then you should be able to bind the connection to a specific address.

Comment: I don't mind if the machine having multiple IP addresses is a requirement. I don't want to spoof other machines IP addresses. Can you specify which address you want to originate from if the machine is bound to multiple addresses? If so how?

Comment: Look into virtual machines.  I *think* the network type you are looking for is "Bridged".  This will allow you to run multiple OS's from the same machine, and each will have its own IP address.

Comment: I need it to be be hosted in the same web application I don't think anyone is going to OK spawning 20 instances of Windows just so we can have a connection pool.

Comment: If windows can't have multiple IP addresses you could add another proxy machine in the middle running a simple linux OS with multiple IP's. It would take multiple connections from your APP and farm the out on different IP's.
I know nothing about it but a google for "linux proxy mutiple ips"
came up with something called squid which seems to do exactly this
http://linuxaria.com/pills/setup-squid-to-use-multiple-outgoing-ip-addresses

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have different local interfaces, you can specify which one you want the socket to bind to when you create the socket. See: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket(java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.net.InetAddress,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29)

Of course, if your traffic is going through any sort of firewall on the way to that other host, it is quite possible that the source IP address on your packets is going to get NATed to something else, and very likely that all the packets you send are going to appear as if they came from the same address anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, it is possible for a single network interface to have multiple IP addresses. I'm absolutely sure for Unix like systems and Windows too, be it with physical network cards or virtual ones.

But they have to all be declared at system level, and your java application will have to manage what address it have to use for each outgoing connexion.

To add a new address to a network interface on Windows, you go into the configuration for that interface and look for the advanced panel. Details may vary depending on Windows version.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd deploy the application (or at least the caller module) to a separate machine (either physically, or on a VPS).

Other (but similar) solution: Implement a proxy for the API, and deploy those small instances to separate machines (again, physical or VPS). Then your code can call the proxy instances, and they will forward the request to the target server.